# How to Find the Sum of the Values of a While Loop

Tags: list, loops, while-loop, sum

My program is set up so that I ask the user for a starting value and then for an ending value. The code is then supposed to take those values and in a 'while loop', output their every integer between the starting and ending value. Also, if the entered starting value is greater than the ending value, then the values are switched. Lastly, the values that were outputted, including the starting and ending values, are supposed to be summed up, but I am not quite sure how to accomplish this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code is given below:

```
starting = int(input('Enter starting number: '))
ending = int(input('Enter ending number: '))
total = 0

while starting < ending + 1:
    print(starting)
    starting = starting + 1

while starting > ending + 1:
    print(ending)
    ending = ending + 1

for itervar in [int(starting) - int(ending)]:
  total = total + itervar

print('Sum is ' + str(total))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes will help your code.

- If the start\end values need to be reversed, just use the tuple syntax
- Do the sum first since the start variable will change later

Try this code:

```
starting = int(input('Enter starting number: '))
ending = int(input('Enter ending number: '))
total = 0

if starting > ending:
   starting, ending = ending, starting  # reverse start\end

for itervar in range(starting,ending+1):  # do sum first
  total = total + itervar
  
while starting < ending + 1:  # print list in order, low to high
    print(starting)
    starting = starting + 1

print('Sum is ' + str(total))
```

Output

```
Enter starting number: 5
Enter ending number: 1
1
2
3
4
5
Sum is 15
```